# Why is this measure not finite, but $\sigma$-finite?

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $\nu$ be the Lebesgue-measure on $[0,1]$, i.e. $\nu=\lambda_{|[0,1]}$ and $\mu(x)=\frac{1}{x}\nu(x)$. Show that $\mu$ isn't finite, but $\sigma$-finite.

**(1)** In order to show, it isn't finite, I have
$$
\mu([0,1])=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{x}\, d\nu=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\, dx=\infty.
$$
But I do not know why I have to go over to Riemann-integral. Why is it allowed?

**(2)** How can I show it's $\sigma$-finite? I have to find $M_n\in\left\{B\cap [0,1]: B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right\}$ with $M_n\uparrow [0,1]$ and $\mu(M_n)<\infty$.

Comment: You don't need to move to the Riemann integral in (1). The Lebesgue integral is well defined for all non-negative measurable functions as an element of $[0,+\infty]$.

Comment: Don't know how to compute $\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{x}\, d\nu(x)$ without turning to Riemann-integral.

Answer (score 1):

(1) If you want to avoid to go back to Riemann integral, you can find a sequence of simple functions $(f_n)$ such that for each $x\in (0,1)$, $0\leqslant f_n(x)\leqslant \frac 1x$ and $\int_{(0,1)}f_n(x)\mathrm d\lambda(x)\geqslant \sum_{j=1}^n\frac 1j$.

(2) Simply consider $M_n:=\{0\}\cup (1/n,1)$.

Comment: What sequence might that be?

Comment: What is then $\mu(M_n)$?Anyhow it is $\mu(M_n)\leqslant 1-\frac{1}{n}<\infty$, right?

Comment: No, $\mu(M_n)=\log n$.

Comment: Why?! And why not $M_n=[1/n,1]$?

Comment: Maybe this is a very sstupid question, but how does one compute the lebesgue integral when there is a function in the integrad like here?

Comment: It's the same thing as singletons have $0$ measure (we however have to include $1$ in order to get the whole closed interval, but it's not a major problem). Either you go back to the definition and approximate by simple functions, or this time you use Riemann integral. You don't need an explicit computation of the measure of $M_n$ if you only want to show this is finite. Indeed the map $x\mapsto 1/x$ is bounded on $(1/n,1)$ by $n$.

Comment: I always have problem to find the reasons why I am allowed to go from Lebesgue-integral to Riemann-integral. What would be the reasoning here?